# Getting wrong lowest value, if I separate the lowest and high (for) loop then I get the correct lowest value

Tags: c++, loops

In 3rd for loop comparison is made for smallest and largest element, I get the wrong value for smallest element. but why I don't understand.
If I divide 3rd loop into 2 for loop, one for lowest element and one for highest element, then I get the correct answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float rainfall[12];
    float total = 0.0;
    float avg = 0.0;
    float high, lowest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cin >> rainfall[i];
    }

    high = rainfall[0];
    lowest = rainfall[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        total = total + rainfall[i];
        avg = total / 12;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        if (rainfall[i + 1] < lowest) {
            lowest = rainfall[i + 1];
        }

        if (rainfall[i + 1] > high) {
            high = rainfall[i + 1];
        }
    }
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << total << endl;
    cout << avg << endl;
    cout << high << endl;
    cout << lowest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax and done.

Comment: If you format your code neatly it should be easier to follow the logic and for others to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has *undefined behaviour*, as you're accessing `rainfall[i+1]` for `i` = `11`.
You should have started at `i` = `1`, and left it as `rainfall[i]`.

---

Notes:

- declare variables at the point where you first need them
- the calculation of `avg` should be performed just once